# Use TRIM in VLOOKUP Table Array Argument in VBA

Tags: vba, excel-formula

Hope you are doing good.

I have a situation where I have to use VLOOKUP formula from one sheet on another sheet, where the Table array contains a lot of spaces. So I would like to trim the Lookup Table Array, but I'm getting errors like "do not match".

Actual Formula:

`MainFileSheet.Range(Cells(2, TeamMemberName), Cells(MainSheetLRow + 1, TeamMemberName)).Value = _ Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(WorksheetFunction.VLookup(MainFileSheet.Range("USFPA[Activity Name]"), Workbooks(UtilizationReport).Sheets("Summary").Range("B:C"), 2, 0), "-")`

I have tried different ways to apply VBA Trim and Worksheetfunction Trim for Table Array. But I'm unable to get the execute the code.

Please help and Thank you in advance.

Comment: "errors like "do not match"" - please can you be more specific?

Comment: Hi @SJR, I'm getting Run time error - 13 (Type Mismatch)

I have used the below code:

`MainFileSheet.Range(Cells(2, TeamMemberName), Cells(MainSheetLRow + 1, TeamMemberName)).Value = _
            Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(WorksheetFunction.VLookup(MainFileSheet.Range("USFPA[Activity Name]"), WorksheetFunction.Trim(Workbooks(UtilizationReport).Sheets("Summary").Range("B:C")), 2, 0), "-")`

Comment: You can't trim a whole range like that, you need to loop through or use helper columns. The first item of a vlookup must be a single cell. You need to fully qualify first bit with sheet references.

Comment: @SJR, My lookup value is in a Table, and Lookup Array is from Pivot Table Data from another workbook. Would you please help me trim the values in Table Array

Comment: What is `Range("USFPA[Activity Name]"`?

Comment: @SJR USFPA is the Table Name and [Activity Name] is the Column Name in that Table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222003/discussion-between-m-rahulkanth-and-sjr).

Comment: As I said, you cannot lookup multiple items in one go, you have to loop through each cell in the range.